# How to center text in RecyclerView

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I have this image:https://drive.google.com/open?id=19D5zqVEdgTS-2zrq9xekzjUdKctv7rSl

But I want it this way:https://drive.google.com/open?id=1T_grwYBUDXP2GENCkFm_Oz-cOvx-qOFR

My RecyclerView

```
<LinearLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".Main2Activity">

<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/lista2"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</LinearLayout>
```

My java code:

```
lista2ParaNotas = findViewById(R.id.lista2);
    lista2ParaNotas.setLayoutManager(new GridLayoutManager(this, 1, GridLayoutManager.VERTICAL,
          false));
    lista2ParaNotas.addItemDecoration(
            new DividerItemDecoration(this,DividerItemDecoration.VERTICAL));



    ArrayList<String> Lista2Notas = (ArrayList<String>) getIntent().getSerializableExtra("miLista");

    AdapterDatos adapter = new AdapterDatos(Lista2Notas);
    lista2ParaNotas.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Please help.

Comment: first use LinearLayoutManager instead of grid layout manager ! and please share the item_design_file for the list items in your recycler view so we could tell how you should write the xml to centerlize the text

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You seem to be using a `GridLayoutManager(...)` instead of `LinearLayoutManager(this)`. You're only displaying a simple list, so I recommend you use Linear.

Also there's a matter of how you did your list item layout. Did you assign a static width to your layout? Have you set it to `layout_centerInParent` if you're using `RelativeLayout`?

Answer (score 0):

It is related to your adapter class's layout, not the code you provided here. Use relative layout in that layout and set align_center_horizontal = "true" in textview attribute.
Show us your adapter class layout if need any further clarification.

Answer (score 0):

Using constraint layout will be even better than using linear or relative layout.